# Android - How to make an activity to load faster?

Tags: android, android-activity, load, sms, performance

I am currently working on an SMS app which will be quite similar to stock sms app.

But the problem is my app is loading much slower than the stock(inbuilt) app.

Here is my app's code :-

```
public class ThreadData extends ListActivity
{
private static final Uri SMS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
ArrayList<String> bodies = new ArrayList<String>();
MySMSAdapter adapter;
String name;

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.threadlist);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        name = extras.getString("address");
    }
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_URI, null, null, null, "date ASC");
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String Id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        String personName = getPersonName(Id,  address);
        if(personName.equals(name))
        {
            bodies.add(body);
        }
    }
    //adapter = new MySMSAdapter(this, bodies);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sms_inbox, R.id.row, bodies);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public String getPersonName(String id, String address)
{
        if(id==null)
        {
            if(address != null)
            {
                return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(address);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, address),
                   new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

        if(c != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if(c.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    return c.getString(0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        if(address != null)
        {
            return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(address);
        }
        return null;
}

}
```

My custom adapter :-

```
public class MySMSAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> data;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MySMSAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> arrayList)
{
    activity = a;
    data = arrayList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount()
{
    return data.size();  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return data.get(i);  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public long getItemId(int i)
{
    return i;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView textView;
}

public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    View row = view;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view==null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_inbox, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(data.get(i));
    return row;
}
}
```

In my class i tried loading List with both the options(custom adapter as well as ArrayAdapter) But in both case my app is loading very slow. How to load it faster? I may prefer solution for my custom adapter as in future i may need few things to add in my layout like photos and other stuff.

Thanks. Please Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html profiler to localize performance issues. My guess the problem is you are doing disk operations (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(...)) synchronously. Try to make this assync using AssyncTask i.e.

Comment: can you please explain a little more that which part of code should i put in AsyncTask because i tried it but its taking the same amount of time but the only difference is that msgs has been loaded one by one rather than all at once. Please explain a little more. :(

Comment: This part     

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_URI, null, null, null, "date ASC");
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String Id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        String personName = getPersonName(Id,  address);
        if(personName.equals(name))
        {
            bodies.add(body);
        }
    }

Comment: I tried both asynctask and traceview. first i want to thank you because i learned two new things - Asynctask and how to use traceview and some adb stuff. I found that the 37% of my app's total performance is consumed by getPersonName(). Do you know any alternative which i can use to get contact person name???? This is my last question and after this i will not bother you at all.

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: You can try to fetch all contacts and put them in you own data structure before iterating through messages. Querying database inside a while loop is certainly slow.